# remote spawn process in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to find the best way to remote spawn a process in Haskell. I actually have only found one author who describes that they serialize a closure and send it. Are there any other ways (thinkable)? Eg. the cost of serializing and sending a closure is certainly high, could there any attempts be made to pre-distribute functions to remote nodes before runtime? Any other comments/ideas?

Comment: Are you referring to [Cloud Haskell](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/parallel/remote.pdf)?

Comment: Yes, but I think about code/process mobility in general and what options might be available.

Answer (score 1):

In Clean you can send PABC bytecode over network.

Here is a general overview of code mobility technologies: http://www.idi.ntnu.no/emner/dif8914/essays/Jingyue-essay2002.pdf

Comment: So the receiving node writes the byte code to hd and starts it? How does the sender discover the presence of a suitable receiver?

Comment: Thanks for the link to the paper. Did you know this: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/stg/workshops/TFP/book/DuBois/duboismhaskell/cameraready.pdf
mHaskell seems to have disappeared.